# Handle dependencies from submodules in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dependencies

i am currently investigating if it is necessary to define each dependency in my submodule either to define it in the main module. I will give you an example my purpose in a better way.

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['Restangular', 'mainApp.books']
```

My submodule "mainApp.books" which is responsible to manage your personal books also needs Restangular to work correctly. Since i have defined mainApp.books as dependency from my mainApp  i don't need to specify Restangular in the submodule to get it work correctly.

```
angular.module('mainApp.books')....
```

Since the books module wouldn't ran as standalone application, i didn't need to specify the dependency of my submodule. How you handle this in your AngularJS projects? Hopefully i could  describe my thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain a bit more

Comment: Every my submodule needs the dependency of "Restangular", so i define the dependency of "Restangular" in my module angular.module('mainApp') - How you handle the dependencies? Define each dependency explicit in your submodule or you define it all in your main module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the right thing, just what you say a `submodule` is not really a `submodule`, it is just a different `module`.

all your modules require to use `restangular`, so you can simply include dependency in your `mainApp` module like you did in your example. and now you can use it inside the `mainApp.books` module without specifying dependency for `restangular`. This is exactly how dependecies are handled in angular. there is  no need for creating dependency in each module or submodule.

The  simple explanation would be, think of dependency as you are combining two modules together as a one large module, so no one would like to include dependency twice in the same module, isn't it.

Comment: Yeah, that was i was thinking about - The problem is, that my modules are not really modules, not working as standalone application, so the definition of dependencies of my modules are a bit confusing, but i am happy that i am doing the right think. ;)